# Java logging framework which runs on a subset of 1.1.8/1.2 and does not depend on java.beans, etc (as log4j does)

Tags: java, logging

I'm working on an application for a device which supports a subset of Java 1.1.8/1.2, specifically the classes in the following packages:

- java.lang
- java.io
- java.util
- java.net
- java.lang.reflect
- java.util.zip
- java.math
- java.text
- java.security

I want to include quite a bit of logging in this application to make troubleshooting and support easier.

Ideally I would use log4j, but even the version of log4j which supports SDK 1.1.8 requires java.beans among other things.

Is there another logging framework which has fewer dependencies, or am I stuck rolling my own?

My plan is to log to disk which means that a feature like log4j's RollingFileAppender would be useful for keeping the logs a reasonable size, but all in all I'm not too picky about features as long as it beats rolling my own (which I will end up doing if I have to).

---

I found the following frameworks, but none of them will work on my device.

- [simple-log](https://simple-log.dev.java.net/): Requires 1.4
- [MicroLog](http://microlog.sourceforge.net/site/): Java ME
- [Java Logging Framework](http://www.theobjectguy.com/javalog/): Unavailable classes
- [Java Logging Suite](http://www.richardsonsoftware.com/rplog/): This might actually work if I do not use the threadsafe logger (which uses Collections.synchronizedList from java.util), but it's basic enough and there are enough differences in my needs that I think I'll be better off rolling my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were unable to find a suitable framework had to write a simple framework of our own.

Answer (score 0):

You say you have java.util, so do you have java.util.logging?

Comment: No. java.util.logging was added in 1.4 (reference: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html).